# SQL query in Grails criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I have a large Grails criteria in which I need to use

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

query, Is there any way I can use this in criteria?. Can I use sqlRestriction in this case?

Comment: What's the domain class look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Restriction is really for where clauses.  You are better off just doing HQL

Comment: Create a couple transients and mapping them to a formula. You can then select that value. One thing to note. If you update the value on the fly you must refresh the domain instance.